# How to efficiently determine the number of points inside a grid cell in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I started learning python and I have trouble figuring out how to tackle the following:

I have a Sorted Numpy array filled with X and Y values:

The range of these values `-73.590 < X < -73.550` and `45.490 < Y < 45.530`

```
[[-73.59  45.49]
 [-73.59  45.49]
 [-73.59  45.49]
 ...
 [-73.55  45.53]
 [-73.55  45.53]
 [-73.55  45.53]]
```

I have a Matplotlib plot divided into a grid of 22x22 cells, each cell is a 0.002 increment on X and Y.

Now I have almost 20,000 entries in my Numpy array and I don't want to do the following:

```
# count all the points in cells from cell 0 to cell 483

for i in range(len(sortedArray)):
    if sortedArray[i][1] <= 45.490 and sortedArray[i][0] <= -73.59:
        cellValue[0] += 1
```

This will take a century and is not efficient of course.

I will set a threshold lets say 50% where if the number of points in a specific cell is higher than this threshold, I will colour it yellow or else purple. Maybe using `imshow()` (also not sure how that'll work)

Anyone has a better idea on how to tackle this ?

Thanks!

edit: Added threshold information

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a histogram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at a [2d histogram](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html). Here's an example with your numbers:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([[-73.59,  45.49],
                 [-73.59,  45.49],
                 [-73.59,  45.49],
                 [-73.55,  45.53],
                 [-73.55,  45.53]])

extenti = (-73.590, -73.550)
extentj = (45.490, 45.530)
hist, *edges = np.histogram2d(data[:,0], data[:,1], bins=22, range=(extenti, extentj))

plt.matshow(hist, extent=np.ravel([extentj, extenti]))
```

[image: example np]

Or more simply:

```
plt.hist2d(data[:,0], data[:,1], bins=22);
```

[image: example plt]

Comment: Hi, is it possible to count how many points fall in each cell? Based on this I want to set a threshold let's say 50%, where each cell with points more than this threshold will be coloured yellow and other blocks would be purple. Thanks

Comment: Yes, the 2d array hist has the number of counts per bin. You could then threshold at 50% as: hist > hist.max()/2

Comment: Thank You! @Paddy